# Remove blur on oversized image

Tags: javascript, css, html, image

I am making a mile high Italian flag, but I don't have enough disk space to make a mile high image with the right aspect ratio. To solve this issue, I decided to make a super small (2 x 3 px) image and display it in a webpage as a mile high. The only issue is that the browser blurs the image, but I want it to appear pixelated so that it would look like the flag (the flag is just 3 equally sized vertical stripes). Is there a way to fix this? The flag is available [here](http://tupperkion.github.io/italy-flag/mile-high-flag.html). Relevant code:

```html
<img src=2-px-high-flag.png width=6842880 height=4561920>
```

**Edit:** I at least want to make it compatible with chrome. Other **additional** browsers would help, too.

Comment: Have you tried doing so by CSS? not with images? Hmm.. do you have a clear example of what you are looking for? pixelated?

Comment: I thought you people used kilometers?

Comment: I'm an american, but I got the idea at a soccer camp and decided to do it.

Comment: Plus, it's easier to do because the flag is really simple.

Comment: Have you looked into using Vector Graphics?  This would be trivial to do as an SVG in Inkscape.  All modern browsers support SVG (http://caniuse.com/svg-img).

Comment: I tried opening the png file, then saving it as an svg, but it still blurred the image. Do I have to do anything special to vectorize the image? Please respond in an answer, so I can properly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use html to do this, as it would take up less memory and will not be dithered.

```
<div class="flag">
    <div class="green"></div>
    <div class="white"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
</div>
```

```
.flag{
    width:6842880px;
    height:4561920px;
}
.flag div{
    float:left;
    width:33.3333333333333333333333%;
    height:100%;
}
.green{
    background:green;
}
.white{
    background:white;
}
.red{
    background:red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Q8y65/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try to make image 6842880x1 with needed colors (2 280 960 pixels for each color)

Comment: The only issue is, I can only put ~300 feet into gimp, because with gimp, it limits the dimensions, assuming you will put it into a square.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to make a table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="green" class="flag"></td>
    <td id="white" class="flag"></td>
    <td id="red" class="flag"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Then, use a style object to format `flag` class to the proper size, and format each of the color ids to their proper color.

```
<style>
  .flag {width:2280960px; height:4561920px}
  /*change colors to real Italian flag colors*/
  #red {background-color:#ff0000}
  #white {background-color:#ffffff} 
  #green {background-color:#00ff00}
</style>
```

It looks just fine to me, no gradients. It may take some calibration or CSS to remove any whitespace between the different flag `div`s.